# android json get request

Tags: php, android, json

I want to print the textview of the user who made the android login process, I first converted the data to json format in php, but when I type database / show.php into the android url part, the textview is typed as null.

Php code :

```
$id=$_GET["id"];
$sql=$conn->prepare("SELECT  id,name,surname,type FROM personel WHERE id='$id'");
$sql->execute();
$result=$sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
echo (json_encode($result));
```

Java code :

```
    final String url = "database/show.php";
    JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest
            (Request.Method.GET, url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {

                    try {

                           if(response.equals("başarılı")) {
                               userId.setText(response.getString("id").toString());
                               userName.setText(response.getString("name"));
                               userSurname.setText(response.getString("surname"));
                               userType.setText(response.getString("type"));
                           }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "error"+error, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

            });
```

// Access the RequestQueue through your singleton class.

> MySingleton.getInstance(this).addToRequestQueue(jsonObjectRequest);

Comment: Paste you JSON response also for better understanding

Comment: When you don't know what the client get, you should paste all the response into the textarea so you know what the server give to you, then you could debug it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see some problems with your code:

1- You didn't pass any id in your `new JsonObjectRequest`, So your php code doesn't GET any id probably.(should be `final String url = "http://127.0.0.1/database/show.php?id=234";`)

2- You treated $id in your query as a string. id is usually an Integer.(should be `WHERE id=$id`)

3- The result of your query would be an array. So your client would get a JSONArray, not a JSONObject.(should be `response.getJSONObject(0).getString("id").toString()`)

4 - And what is `if(response.equals("başarılı"))`? Comparing a JSON type with a String type?

Answer (score 0):

I have some suggestions:
1. You are calling database, but id is null. Why don't you try database/show.php?id=2 for example, and use all the url http//../database/show.php?id=2
2. Please load json file to help you a little more